# Cannot connect to a private website using OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

I'm trying to connect to a website using OpenVPN. I've been sent all the necessary login credentials and configuration file  by the owner. I do the following steps:

1. `openvpn --config config.ovpn`
2. Entering username and password
3. It looks like that connection is successful, the last line in terminal says:

   2021-09-21 09:33:12 Initialization Sequence Completed
4. I'm  opening Chromium browser and trying to go to the website, but the error, 403 Forbidden, pops up.

Could you help me to understand what problem might be with?

My system:  ubuntu 18.04,
OpenVPN version: 2.5.3 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: Which VPN provider is that? Or is that a VPN from a company or so? Is the site you try to access located in Russia? Did it work before?

Comment: It's a VPN from a company; I'm not sure where the site is located, but I know that my colleague successfully accesses it. Unfortunately, he doesn't know how to help me with the problem.

Comment: I'm just asking because russia has banned several VPN providers. But in your case I don't know either.